# Rendering react navigation screens inside a scrollview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am building a react native app where I want to add a scrollview as a wrapper to all the UI screens. I have wrapped the `Stack.Navigator` in a ScrollView but the content is clipped at the bottom of the screen, there is no content visible after the end of screen.
Kindly look at the code below

App.tsx

```
export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  return loading ? (
    <AppSplashScreen onLoadComplete={() => setLoading(false)} />
  ) : (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Provider>
          <ScrollView
            contentContainerStyle={{ minHeight: "100%", overflow: "visible" }}
            style={styles.container}
          >
            <Content />
          </ScrollView>
        </Provider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 32,
    padding: 16,
    minHeight: "100%",
  },
});
```

Content.tsx

```
const Content = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="LandingPage"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="LandingPage" component={Signup} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to ScrollView style or contentContainerStyle

flexGrow: 1

Answer (score 0):

Removing padding fixed the issue for me.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 32,
    minHeight: "100%",
  },
});
```